# Is there anything in Dart that would work like an `abstract mixin`?

Tags: dart, oop, mixins

I am trying to write a mockable client for our backend system.

Our setup looks like this:

> MyBackend
> ┣ Base
> ┃ ┣ my_client.dart
> ┃ ┣ int_repo.dart
> ┃ ┗ string_repo.dart
> ┣ Default Impl
> ┃ ┣ my_client_impl.dart
> ┃ ┣ int_repo_impl.dart
> ┃ ┗ string_repo_impl.dart
> ┣ Mock Impl
> ┃ ┣ etc...

What I am trying to accomplish looks something like this:

```
abstract class MyClient with IntRepo, StringRepo {
    MyClientConfig get config;
}

class MyClientImpl with IntRepoImpl, StringRepoImpl {
    @override
    final MyClientConfig config = ...;

    // No logic needed to support int or string repos
}

class MyClientMock with IntRepoMock, StringRepoMock {
    @override
    final MyClientConfig config = ...;

    // No logic needed to support int or string repos
}
```

Which would have end points defined as so:

```
abstract mixin StringRepo {
    Future<String> getString();

    @override
    Future<String> getString() => ...;
}

mixin StringRepoMock extends StringRepo {
    /// Some end point that depends on `MyClientMock.config`
    @override
    Future<String> getString() => ...;
}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
void main() async {
    final client = MyClientImpl(...);
    // final client = MyClientMock(...);

    final value = await client.getString();
}
```

However, this pseudo-code depends on being able to define the abstract mixins `IntRepo` and `StringRepo`.

I got close to the behavior I'm looking for by doing the following:

```
abstract interface class StringRepo {
    Future<String> getString();
}
    
mixin StringRepoImpl on MyClient implements StringRepo {
    /// Some end point that depends on `MyClientImpl.config`
    @override
    Future<String> getString() => ...;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible, since mixins can't be abstract, nor can they extend each other.

The issue I have with this work-around is that the burden of the interface is borne on `MyClient`, meaning that if I add `getAnotherString()`, the error is thrown in `my_client_impl.dart`, rather than in `string_repo_impl.dart`.

In other words, `MyClientImpl` is required to implement `getAnotherString()`, but I want to force `StringRepoImpl` to implement it instead.

Am I trying to reinvent the wheel here or is there some language feature that dart is missing that can do this?

Comment: As of Dart 3.0.0 you can define an `abstract mixin class`, see https://dart.dev/language/mixins#abstract-mixin-class. However, an `abstract mixin class` has the same restrictions as a mixin, for example it can't be extended.

Comment: All mixins are abstract. They can't extend each other, though. But something that's abstract and can be combined is an `interface`. Can you me more concerete about what you want to *achieve*, not just how you want to do it?

Comment: I am trying to create an mockable API client.

There is business logic involved in sending a query/mutation that lives inside my_client.dart, so all the queries need to be sent in some form from MyClient.  

I don't want to have any query-specific logic inside of MyClient (since there's quite a lot of it), but I don't want users to have to import each of the repos individually.

Comment: To clarify, the goal of this refactor is that my current solution has a long list of queries in MyClient that redirect to a different file that builds the query that the client then sends, receives, parses, etc.